# Primary decomposition of modules - uniqueness proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

> Let $M$ be $A$-module, $A$ commutative ring, and $N$ submodule and let
>   $$N=Q_1\cap\dots\cap Q_r=Q'_1\cap \dots \cap Q'_s$$ be reduced primary decompositions of $N$. Then $r=s$. The set of primes belonging to $Q_1,\dots,Q_r$ and $Q'_1,\dots,Q'_r$ is the same.

It is part of theorem 3.2 in Chapter X of Lang's *Algebra*, and he said that proof follows from this theorem (3.5):

> Let $A$ and $M$ be Noetherian. The associated primes of $M$ are precisely the primes belonging to the primary modules in a reduced primary decomposition of $0$ in $M$.

I don't see how it follow from this proof since we need both module and ring to be Noetherian in second theorem? Is there some direct proof for first statement (I tried to prove it myself but without success).

Just some definitions for clarity:

- Submodule $Q$ of $M$ is primary if for every $a\in A$ function $a_{M/Q}:M\rightarrow M$, $a_{M/Q}(x)=ax$ is either injective or nilpotent. And set of all $a\in A$ for which that function is nilpotent is prime ideal which belongs to $Q$.
- Primary decomposition is reduced if primes that belong to different submodules in decompositions are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $N=Q_1\cap\cdots\cap Q_n$ is a reduced primary decomposition, and $P_i=\sqrt{Q_i}$, then $\operatorname{Ass}(M/N)=\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}$.

We have an exact sequence $0\to M/N\to\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M/Q_i$. Then $\operatorname{Ass}(M/N)\subseteq\operatorname{Ass}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M/Q_i)$. But $\operatorname{Ass}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M/Q_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Ass}(M/Q_i)=\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}$.

For the converse, pick up an $x_i\in\bigcap_{j\ne i}Q_j\setminus Q_i$. Now notice that the submodule $Ax_i$ of $M/N$ is isomorphic to the submodule $Ax_i$ of $M/Q_i$ and hence they have the same associated prime ideals. But on one hand $\operatorname{Ass}(Ax_i)\subseteq\operatorname{Ass}(M/N)$, and on the other hand $\operatorname{Ass}(Ax_i)\subseteq\operatorname{Ass}(M/Q_i)=\{P_i\}$. In order to conclude now that $P_i\in\operatorname{Ass}(M/N)$ we have to be sure that $\operatorname{Ass}(Ax_i)\neq\emptyset$, and this requires the assumption $A$ noetherian (no assumption on $M$ is needed!).

Comment: Hi, I have some questions regarding your answer, I hope you can clarify them for me: (1) by the notation $P_i = \sqrt{Q_i}$, do you mean that $P_i$ is the prime belonging to $Q_i$, i.e. $Q_i$ is $P_i$-primary? I have only seen the notation $\sqrt{I}$ used when referring to the radical of the ideal $I$, so I am a bit confused.

Comment: (2) Lang proves that if $A$ and $M \neq 0$ are Noetherian, then the submodule $Q \neq M$ is primary if and only if $M/Q$ has a unique associated prime (this is Proposition X.3.4). In your answer, you do not assume *a priori* that $A$ and $M$ are Noetherian, but you write $\mathrm{Ass}(M/Q_i) = \{ P_i \}$. Does this mean you are working under the additional hypothesis that $M/Q_i$ has a unique associated prime for each $i$?

Comment: (3) I see that $\mathrm{Ass}(\bigoplus M/Q_i) \supset \bigcup \mathrm{Ass}(M/Q_i)$, but how do I prove the reverse inclusion? Sorry about the multiple comments, I would really appreciate some clarification on these points.

Comment: (1) The notation is standard and your guess is right.

Comment: (2) If $Q$ is $P$-primary then $\mathrm{Ass}(M/Q)=\{P\}$ without any extra conditions.

Comment: (3) This is a standard result. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101058/set-of-associated-primes-of-direct-sum).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will spend a few minutes on (2) and (3). If things are still unclear to me, I might be disturbing you with additional pings.

Comment: I went over Lang's proof of Proposition X.3.4 again, and indeed he does not use the hypothesis that $M$ is noetherian in proving that if $Q \neq M$ is a primary submodule of $M$ then $M/Q$ has exactly one associated prime. (The hypothesis that $M$ is noetherian is used in proving the converse.) Part (3) is also clear to me now from the linked answer. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I went through Lang's proof once again, and although he says to use Corollary X.2.11, which in turn uses Propositions X.2.9 and X.2.10 and Corollary X.2.7, each of which assume that $A$ is noetherian, if I carefully retrace the steps used in proving the implication $$Q \neq M \text{ is } \mathfrak{p}\text{-primary} \implies \operatorname{Ass}(M/Q) = \{\mathfrak{p}\}$$ then I see that the hypothesis that $A$ is noetherian is not needed. Phew.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd suggest you to study the primary decomposition from a Commutative Algebra textbook, e.g. Matsumura, Bourbaki. They are more careful with the conditions than a general algebra textbook as Lang.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am planning to take a graduate course next semester based on Matsumura's book. I have not yet looked at any of Bourbaki's books, but I will do so now.

Comment: Since $\operatorname{Ass}(Ax_i)\neq\emptyset\iff Ax_i\neq\emptyset$, it suffices to let $\cap_{j\ne i}Q_j\setminus Q_i\ne\emptyset$. How does Noetherian insure $\cap_{j\ne i}Q_j\setminus Q_i\ne\emptyset$?

Comment: @Bach That follows from the reducedness of the primary decomposition, not from Noetherianity.