# Classification of associated primes of a module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module. I am interested in classifying the associated primes of $M$.

I know that $M$ is an $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it is an abelian group. So I think I can make use of the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. But I am stuck on how to use it to classify the associated primes of $M$.

Any hint/help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101058